# MySQL server requested caching_sha2_password for a user with standard password

Tags: mysql

I have MySQL database up and running with the caching_sha2_password authentication.

It allows for creating users with the standard password authentication (mysql_native_password) but when trying to connect from a remote host with standard auth the user I'm getting 'The server requested authentication method unknown to the client [caching_sha2_password]...' error anyway.

Is it possible to use the legacy authentication for selected users even if the server supports caching_sha2_password.
The reason would be e. g. using strong authentication for the root and standard for the other accounts with limited access to single schemas.

(Version 8.0.16 GPL)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out that problem was on the client side – PHP 7 compatibility issues with MySQL 8.

Helpful link: https://github.com/laradock/laradock/issues/1130

After upgrading PHP to 7.3 my problem vanished.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the authentication method for each user individually in the `plugin` column of the `mysql.user` table. Check the documentation [6.2.3 Grant Tables - The user and db Tables](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/grant-tables.html#grant-tables-user-db):

> The server uses the plugin named in the `plugin` column of an account row to authenticate connection attempts for the account.